# Apache storm 2.4.0 working slow compared to apache storm 0.9.6

Tags: apache-storm, apache-storm-topology, apache-storm-configs

I am migrating to apache storm 2.4.0 from apache storm 0.9.6
But the performance in apache storm 2.4.0 is slower.

I read that wait strategy plays role in performance
Exiting application on apache storm 0.9.6 has following wait strategy configuration

```
topology.spout.wait.strategy: backtype.storm.spout.SleepWaitStrategy
topology.disruptor.wait.strategy: com.lmax.disruptor.BlockingWaitStrategy
topology.disruptor.wait.timeout.millis: 1000
topology.sleep.spout.wait.strategy.time.ms: 1
```

Tried tweaking wait strategy parameter in apache storm 2.4.0.
Following tests i had performed

1. Kept all defaults as it is
2. 

```
topology.bolt.wait.progressive.level1.count:0
topology.bolt.wait.progressive.level2.count:0
topology.bolt.wait.progressive.level3.sleep.millis:0
topology.backpressure.wait.progressive.level1.count:0
topology.backpressure.wait.progressive.level2.count:0
topology.backpressure.wait.progressive.level3.sleep.millis:0
```

3. 

```
topology.spout.wait.strategy:org.apache.storm.policy.WaitStrategy
topology.backpressure.wait.strategy:org.apache.storm.policy.WaitStrategy
topology.bolt.wait.strategy:org.apache.storm.policy.WaitStrategy
topology.bolt.wait.microsec:0
```

But performance was lot slower in all scenarios. What other factors we can check for performance testing while migrating?
How to improve performance in apache storm 2.4.0?